# How to sort column wise based on custom values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, columnsorting

I have a data frame as follows:

```
columnA_1,  columnB_1,  columnC_1,  columnA_2,  columnB_2,  columnC_2,  …   columnA_n,  columnB_n,  columnC_n
A,              1,         DD,         D,           1,         BV,              C,         9,           MH
B,            1.1,        FGH,         A,           4,         RG,              F,       1.1,           DW
C,              2,         CC,         A,           2,         CC,              B,         7,           AD
D,            2.7,         TT,         D,           6,         JJ,              A,         2,           LI
```

`ColumnB` and `columnC` are associated with `columnA`, I want to sort column wise based on the value in the `columnA`.
based on the sorted position of `columnA`, I also need to move the corresponding `columnB` and `columnC` along with it.

Here the values in columnA are given as alphabet for the simplification, but in reality, I have a list of string values according to the priorities. In this example, the expected output is shown in an alphabetically sorted manner.

for eg, if I am choosing the sorting based on reverse alphabetic order, the string would look like

`order=['Z','Y','X',...,'A']`

Based on this list, I need to sort the above columns. **The final column names are not important.**
The expected output of the example is given below:

```
columnA_1,  columnB_1,  columnC_1,  columnA_2,  columnB_2,  columnC_2,  …   columnA_n,  columnB_n,  columnC_n
A,             1,           DD,         C,         9,          MH,              D,         1,           BV  
A,             4,           RG,         B,       1.1,         FGH,              F,       1.1,           DW  
A,             2,           CC,         B,         7,          AD,              C,         2,           CC  
A,             2,           LI,         D,         6,          JJ,              D,       2.7,           TT
```

Should I need to clarify more? How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df[:] = df.apply(
    lambda row: [
        v
        for tpl in sorted(
            zip(row[::3], row[1::3], row[2::3]), key=lambda v: v[0]
        )
        for v in tpl
    ],
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)


print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  columnA_1  columnB_1 columnC_1 columnA_2  columnB_2 columnC_2 columnA_n  columnB_n columnC_n
0         A        1.0        DD         C        9.0        MH         D        1.0        BV
1         A        4.0        RG         B        1.1       FGH         F        1.1        DW
2         A        2.0        CC         B        7.0        AD         C        2.0        CC
3         A        2.0        LI         D        2.7        TT         D        6.0        JJ
```

Comment: How to include the list variable `order` in this one for the custom sort?

Comment: @VGB You can make custom key function. For example `key=lambda v: order.index(v[0])`

Comment: How could I skip the element if it is not in the `order` list? I am looking for particular elements to sort. How could I modify the function? 
I am sorry I find it hard to decipher the code even though it works perfectly.

Comment: @VGB You can make `order` a dictionary instead of a `list` and use `dict.get` method with default value.